# How to play a mp3 in monogame

Tags: c#, media-player, monogame

I want to use background music in my game so i used this code:

```
private Song backgroundMusic;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    ....
    backgroundMusic = Content.Load<Song>("backgroundMusic");
    MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
    MediaPlayer.Play(backgroundMusic);
}
```

but when running the program i get this exception:

```
 "System.DllNotFoundException" in SharpDX.MediaFoundation.dll
```

additional information:

```
DLL "Mfplat.dll": Module could not be found. (Exception HRESULT: 0x8007007E) loading not possible.
```

Allthough i had to translate the error message i hope you can do something with it. Also there is no winsows media player running on my system (i use vlc player). Is that a possible reason for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just did a little research seems it has something to do with your trying to access a windows media library need to install the newest media features pack 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231